# Detect password manager (or chromium) autofill for websites

Tags: reactjs, input, autofill, password-autofill

I have a React app & in my Login page with SignInInput.tsx (Inputs) components. I already deployed it in the web but i have the problem that the autocomplete of chrome doesn't get detected by the onChange or onAnimationStart properties. I've been looking for hours.
[The page with the autofill pas[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6slWb.png)sword manager on loading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peh2T.png)
[When i click in the inputs the font changes & the onChange detect the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f33WD.png)

I have try to add a onAnimationEnd and onAnimationStart, a useEffect a useMemo, but the autofill gets in after the page is loaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvxZr.png)